# Install NCurses on python3 for Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ncurses, python-curses

I'm having issues installing `ncurses` for `Python3`. When I did the normal `sudo apt-get install ncurses-dev`, it appeared to install for `Python2` but when I try to run my script for `Python3`, it says.

```
ImportError: No module named curses
```

How would you get `ncurses` to work for `Python3`?

Answer (score 8):

I had this same problem. The issue was that ncurses was not installed on my Ubuntu installation. To fix it, I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev
```

and then reinstalled Python. In my case with:

```
pyenv install 3.8.1
```

Answering y when asked **continue with installation? (y/N)**

This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import curses
```

curses is ncurses. It's also built in to python, there's nothing to install.

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-65-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Mon Oct 19 19:06:03 2015 from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
me@ubuntu:~$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Jun 19 2015, 14:20:21) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import curses
>>>
```

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Comment: Is there anything here: `/usr/lib/python3.4/curses`?

Comment: I just tried typing what you did and when I did "import curses", it says No module named '_curses'. Yes, I do have stuff in there. Though it's weird that I have a python3 and python3.4 folder in there.

Comment: I think i found the issue... Python is automatically running 3.5 so it isn't picking up the curses library in 3.4. I don't know how to fix it to default in 3.4 but I can just run "python3.4 main.py" to run my script.

Comment: How did you install python3.5?

Comment: I went to the python website cause I didn't know that python3.4 was automatically installed already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93018/discussion-between-jgritty-and-solomon).